# MySQL - How to insert a possibly null value

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null

I have some values in a PHP script that I must insert in a MySQL table. Here is for example 3 dates `d1`, `d2`, and `d3`.

I have that default statement to insert the values into the database:

```
insert into mytable set a=1, b=2, d1='$val', d2='$val2', d3='$val3'
```

Is there a very simple way I can write the SQL statement to insert into d1, d2 and d3 NULL values instead of a date if one (or more) of `$val1`, `$val2` and `$val3` is nil ? Without having to deal with new PHP variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that way to be the simpliest way to do what I wanted to do:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET a=1, b=2, d1=IF('$val' = '', NULL, '$val');
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have it all in `$data` array:

```
$query_string = "insert into mytable set a=1, b=2, d1=" .
    (isset($data['val1']) ? "'" . $data['val1'] . "'" : 'NULL') . ", d2=" .
    (isset($data['val2']) ? "'" . $data['val2'] . "'" : 'NULL') . ", d3=" .
    (isset($data['val3']) ? "'" . $data['val3'] . "'" : 'NULL') . ";";
```

The string will contain eg. `d2=NULL` instead of `d2='xyz'`, if the value in array does not exist or is equal to `null`.

You have to also make sure that the strings you want to paste into the query are properly sanitized (eg. using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)). **My answer treats your variables as already prepared and sanitized**, as you only wanted to know **how to insert `NULL` values instead of the variables you have.**

Because the question was only about entering `NULL` values in the query based on the value of variables, I do not think discussing sanitization in detail here would be a good idea. You can find a lot more detailed info on SQL Injection and how to prevent it in PHP here: [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php). Good luck! :)

Comment: @Kenaniah: What parameter injection are you talking about? Explain yourself for future readers. If you are talking about SQL Injection, then I believe your downvote is based on assumption that the data is not escaped. I did not make that assumption - I answered OP's question.

Comment: `$data[$x]` has not been properly escaped to handle quoting issues. For example, if `$data['val1']` contains a `'`, your query no longer operates correctly and is then exposed to malicious injection attacks.

Comment: @Kenaniah: As I said, you downvoted my answer because I did not escape the data, even though you have **no** reasons to believe the data is not sanitized! What if `$val1`, `$val2` and `$val3` from OP's example are all integers or `NULL`'s? You are killing me. [Assumption is a mother of all screw ups](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc). I answered the question, did not assume it is user-provided data.

Comment: as you pointed out, assumption is the mother of all screw ups, and you for some reason assume that the data coming in is actually sanitized. Your "what if" of integers and nulls is nowhere supported in the OP. The downvote stands.

Comment: @Kenaniah: Ever saw data that has been unnecessarily double-escaped? The question was precise, however I will put proper information into the answer. But as OP has stated, the application already existed and whatever he did to sanitize the data is his concern. You downvoted correct answer because of your assumption. The worst thing in this is that it was not due to answer's incorrectness, but due to it not performing what you assumed should be done ;) Cheers!

Comment: you didn't even mention sanity checks in your answer, nor has the OP said anything about sanitization. Blindly reading your answer and copy/pasting could prove to be dangerous. Error on the side of caution.

Comment: @Kenaniah: I did not say anything about opening the script with `<?php`, about where the script should be placed, what mechanism for authorization / authentication should be used, why storing data in raw cookies can be dangerous, what is CSRF or XSS, which PHP framework is better, what is `mod_rewrite` nor what is JavaScript used for. Does it make my answer incorrect? No. Wait, maybe it is? SO is about asking questions & answering questions. I have answered a question, I did not try to write the whole application for the OP ;) But fortunately you are here to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a better way to do this, but if all else fails, you can do this with each of your values:

```
$val = isset($val) ? "'$val'" : "NULL";
```

Then change your PHP query string to this:

```
insert into mytable set a=1, b=2, d1=$val, d2=$val2, d3=$val3
```

You should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of building a query string like that, especially if there is user input involved in your variables.

Comment: Oliver, http://us2.php.net/pdo. Please read the manual before you attempt programming.

Comment: Thank you. I'll think about that... one day. In fact I'm not a newbie in php, but I don't have time to read the full doc each time a new version of php is released. I had developped a site in PHP 3.0, it works, and I just want to maintain it, not to rewrite it from scratch to implement a great-cool-extra feature that I don't need at this time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to define

```
function esc_null($src) {
    return $src === null ? 'NULL' : ("'" + mysql_real_string_escape($src) + "'");
}

"insert into mytable set a=1, b=2, d1=" . esc_null($val) . ", d2=" . esc_null($val2) . ", d3=" . esc_null($val3)
```

This as well ensures integrity of your queries.

Comment: Your solution ensures that if `$val` is equal to `nil`, then the following string will be inserted in the query: " `d1='NULL'` ". If you did not spot the difference: this is a 4-letter string " _NULL_ " instead of actual `NULL` value.

Comment: -1 for parameter injection issues. Also for `nil`. PHP uses `null`.

Comment: @Kenaniah:ok, but with some edit, this could be a great answer.

Comment: @Oliver: Of course it can, but it should insert `NULL` instead of `'NULL'`, when the `$val` etc. are equal to `NULL`.

Comment: Oops. I changed it now to be hopefully correct. I already had this "'" stuff on my mind. But, @Kenaniah, AFAICT `nil` and the `'NULL'` instead of `NULL` were the only issues. Where are/were there parameter injection issues? I had `mysql_real_escape()` around all variables (what even was my point here). Where can there be something injected?

Comment: I removed the downvote, but code is still broken. When I saw the post initially, it wasn't escaped. BTW, please put quotes around the caps NULL, as PHP will interpret that as a literal null. The line should read `return $src === null ? 'NULL' : "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($src) . "'";`