# PHP with mySQL NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, null

```
$newusr_group = $type;
$newusr_name = $_POST['name'];
$newusr_world = $_POST['world'];
if(!$newusr_world) {
    $newusr_world = mysql_escape_string(NULL);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `permissions_inheritance` (`id`, `child`, `parent`, `type`, `world`)VALUES(NULL, '$newusr_name', '$newusr_group', '1', '".$newusr_world."');";
```

I get a few values from a form submission, and I check if $newuser_world is blank - if it is then I need to set it to MySQL NULL, or the application which reads the database does not use the row for some reason.

So my question is:

How do I set a PHP Variable which tells the query to submit a MySQL `NULL` value?

I've searched Stack Overflow and Google to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING** Your code is suseptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This isn't the full code, Daniel. You have to log-in as an admin user to even display this page.

Comment: please stop used the ancient `mysql_*` functions and learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) with prepared statements

Comment: @Daniel: The code is probably just a dummy for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Just because it requires admin access doesn't mean that someone won't accidentally screw things up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - How to insert a possibly null value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304276/mysql-how-to-insert-a-possibly-null-value)

Answer (score 1):

That would be `NULL`. Also, your code, as @DanielAWhite points out, is susceptible to attack, and both of those issues can be fixed in one go:

```
$newusr_group = $type;
$newusr_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$newusr_world = $_POST['world'];

if($newusr_world) {
    $newusr_world = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($newusr_world) . "'";
} else {
    $newusr_world = 'NULL';
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `permissions_inheritance`(`id`, `child`, `parent`, `type`, `world`)
        VALUES(NULL, '$newusr_name', '$newusr_group', '1', '$newusr_world');";
```

Comment: @2xAA: Welcome, happy to help! (Strange, I didn't get a comment notification though...)

Comment: +1 I know there's debate about whether this is real code or not, but just to be careful, I'd like to point out that the code here is still vulnerable to SQL injection, via `$newusr_name` (and perhaps `$newusr_group`). It's best to use some universal (to your code base) mechanism instead of always having to remember to sanitize each value.

Comment: @grossvogel: Oops, completely missed that. Thanks. (Real or not, I like to post good code.)

Answer (score 1):

To insert a NULL value, just write NULL instead of the value you would insert. See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-null.html

Answer (score 0):

do it this way:

```
$newusr_world = trim($_POST['world']);
```

This will ensure that even if spaces are entered by the user on the input field it will automatically set it null because ' ' will be converted to '' and '' on mysql is already equivalent to NULL also. :)

Comment: Are you saying mysql treats the empty string as null? That's not true in my experience.

Comment: ok if that is the case then we could have another approach like this $sql = "INSERT INTO `permissions_inheritance` (`id`, `child`, `parent`, `type`, `world`)VALUES(NULL, '$newusr_name', '$newusr_group', '1', ".(empty($newusr_world) ? 'NULL' : "'{$newusr_world}'").");"; on the statement the empty will check if the newusr_world variable is empty cause '' = null = 0 = array() that is how empty function works.

Comment: @colighto: Please edit that into your answer, then. We can't read it here, especially without proper code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

ok if that is the case then we could have another approach like this

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO 
permissions_inheritance (
 id, 
 child, 
 parent, 
 type, 
 world)
VALUES(NULL, 
 '$newusr_name', 
 '$newusr_group', 
 '1', 
 ".(empty($newusr_world) ? 'NULL' : "'{$newusr_world}'")."
);";
```

on the statement the empty will check if the newusr_world variable is empty cause '' = null = 0 = array() that is how empty function works.

Comment: Please Consider the SQL Injection

Comment: @UserB It's up to him to consider that.

Answer (score -2):

Try;

```
$newusr_world = (!empty($newusr_world)) ? $newusr_world : NULL;
$sql="INSERT INTO `permissions_inheritance` (`child`, `parent`, `type`, `world`) VALUES ('$newusr_name', '$newusr_group', '1', '".$newusr_world."');";
```

Comment: WARNING Your code is suseptible to SQL injection attacks.  
that was the first comment